# How do I publish an activity on facebook using the Graph API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

The old Facebook Legacy REST API had a function `dashboard.publishActivity`, however the new Graph API only allows messages to be posted on `/me/feed`.

Is there a way to send activities using the Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/552/ Facebook "have removed the section which displayed the News that developers published via the Dashboard APIs in the Games Dashboard". Therefore the dashboard.publishActivity function no longer provides any useful functionality. My recommendation is to switch to either using stream posts or to Requests 2.0, as these will provide the same sort of distribution that you're looking for.